# My windows path var (and seemingly all vars) stopped working from my shell

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-11

I'm very familiar with env vars. I've used them for the last decade across any OS with no issues. I say this just to reduce basic trouble shooting chatter.

I have no idea what I did or installed that did this. Suddenly just nothing expands. echo %path% doesn't work etc. This issue persists across reboots. When the basics don't work, I don't always know where to look. Where do I start with this?

It's not just expansion though. I can't call commands from path either. wsl for example.

edit: So if I run as admin, it works. The path var is set for my user. Perhaps it's some sort of profile option I've modified. In linux, thats something like ~/.bashrc. I bet windows is more esoteric.

Comment: If `echo %path%` "doesn't work", what does it do instead – expand to an empty string or remain unexpanded? What environment variables *do* you have in Cmd, i.e. what does the `set` built-in command output? What environment variables do parent processes have (as seen in Sysinternals ProcExp)?

Comment: it just echos "%path%" which if I recall was not the case recently. Admin terminal works as expected. I'll bet it's something weird with the new 11 terminal. I just don't know where to look. I've foobar'd something for my user specifically, but path is properly set

Comment: Are you actually working in the Cmd shell, then, and not in PowerShell? Windows has been switching to PowerShell as default in the last few years, and it has a different expansion syntax – `%` is not a special character. Try `$env:PATH` and see if that works?